# Not able to connect SQL server via Kerberos authentication

Tags: sql-server

I have some problem in connecting SQL server via kerberos authentication. Below is my configuration details.

I have 2 machines. **M1** (Domain controller) & **M2** (SQL server installed)

1) In M1 I have installed AD and configured kerberos.

2) In M2 I have installed SQL server 2012 and configured the service to use the domain account which I have created in the AD.

3) Enabled TCP/IP and modified the client protocol order to TCP/IP as the first to consider

3) Installed Kerberos Configuration Manager on M2 and created SPN like

**MSSQLSvc/FQDN**
**MSSQLSvc/FQDN:TCPPORT**

4) In M1 -> AD -> For my SQL server domain account I have added the SPN & also added Delegation for kerberos authentication(to any service).

5) In M2 I am running this query in **SQL Management Studio** and it always returning result as NTLM.

**select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid**

Can anyone let me know where I am wrong & what I am missing. Thanks for your help /\

Comment: First of all, if you are connecting to a local instance of SQL Server (that is, you are locally logged on) the authentication scheme is always NTLM and never Kerberos. It's slightly misleading, but essentially it means no Kerberos server needed to be contacted to verify the credentials. (This is also why such logins succeed even if the SQL Server isn't set up properly to do domain auth.)  Try connecting from another machine, and take care to use the actual machine name in that case (not a TCP address or DNS alias); this should show an `auth_scheme` of `KERBEROS`.

Comment: Note that enabling delegation is not typically necessary -- this only comes into play with multi-hop authentication and linked servers (sometimes). There are [good reasons](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2017/06/30/credential-theft-made-easy-with-kerberos-delegation/) this isn't enabled by default, and it tends to not be the correct solution to most problems -- including authenticating with SQL Server. Even where it is, it needs to be treated with care.

Comment: Last but certainly not least, it isn't typically necessary to make SQL Server use a domain account either. If it will not be accessing resources beyond the local machine (the most common scenario) having it run under a local account (like a [virtual account](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts)) simplifies account management. As long as it has its SPNs properly configured, it will be able to do domain authentication. Using a domain account certainly has its uses, but becomes a potential security issue if it's shared between servers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Checked the connection from a third machine and kerberos is working fine.